# Save a view in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player, media-player

I like to view my library in various ways in WMP. For example, I usually search for Podcast and order the result by date added. This gives me a list of my podcasts by date order, newest to oldest. Is there a way of saving this view so that I don't have recreate it each time I open WMP?

If it's not possible to do this, can anyone suggest an app that does do it, and that handles syncing as well as WMP.

Comment: Id say impossible... Can't find anytthing on this. All I know is that organize will give you options to change it. Nothing on saving those views

Answer (score 2):

I could find [how to hack the background](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/06/hack-to-change-windows-media-player-12-wmp12-library-view-background-image/) through the registry

By looking into the Media Player Preferences

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences

Perhaps a more knowledgable person knows which one of these would "reset" your view, so that you can turn it off and leave it as you set it.